# Web Setup Wizard - CronJob Setup - Magento 2 Error Update

Tags: magento2

I'm getting this error and I can't figure out what I"m doing wrong.

```
Check Cron Scripts
Cron script readiness check failed. Hide detail

Error from Setup Application Cron Script:
Cron job has not been configured yet
Other checks will fail as a result (PHP version, PHP settings, and PHP extensions)
```

I can run crontab -e and it says "Ran jobs by schedule." in the terminal but when I check the log files I'm getting this message below.

```
bin/magento must be run as a CLI application
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.27
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

I installed magento onto shared hosting at godaddy and all is fine I just can't use the "web setup wizard" to update the application and I wanted to make sure all is working. I'm getting errors running that damn thing can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: try php bin/magento cron:run

Comment: I'm already using that.